# Mercurial - How to configure multiline hook on Windows

Tags: powershell, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, mercurial-hook, hgrc

Running Windows 7, configuring a commit hook in my .hgrc file.

The hook calls an external powershell script and passes it a few parameters.  When I put all the parameters on one long line, the script receives them just fine.  However, when I try to put each parameter on its own line, the hook can't figure out that they are all part of the same call to my external script.

[hooks]

```
commit.working_one_liner = PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\MyScript.ps1 -hg %HG% -updatedToChangeset %HG_NODE% -dbName 'Test'

commit.multi_line_hook_not_working = PowerShell.exe 
    -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
    -File .\MyScript.ps1
    -hg %HG%
    -updatedToChangeset %HG_NODE%
    -dbName 'Test'
```

According to the [Hg documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#syntax), I should be able to do this:

"A configuration file consists of sections, led by a [section] header and followed by name = value entries (sometimes called configuration keys):

```
[spam]
eggs=ham
green=
   eggs
```

Each line contains one entry. If the lines that follow are indented, they are treated as continuations of that entry. Leading whitespace is removed from values. Empty lines are skipped. Lines beginning with # or ; are ignored and may be used to provide comments."

Despite indenting, the multi_line_hook seems to ignore everything after the first line.  I've tried various escape characters (`, ^, \, etc.) after each new line.  Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The example from the documentation only works for the first line to follow and not the rest.

I don't have access to windows at the moment, but on linux I need to use a backslash:

```html
[hooks]
commit.working = echo \
    test
```